# Take a path of a bitmap image and convert it into Base64

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to take a path of an image like:
"content://media/external/images/media/3"

and convert it into a base64 string.

Here is the code I have now:

```
public String ConvertandSetImagetoBase64(String imagePath) { 
    String base64 = null;
    byte[] input = null;

    try{
        FileInputStream fd = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
        Bitmap bmt = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFD());

        try{                
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap tmp = ProfileActivity.scaleDownBitmap(bmt, 10, this);
            tmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
            input = stream.toByteArray();
            base64 = Base64.encodeToString(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
            //LocalProfileActivity.input = input;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"[ONACTIVITYRESULT] Could not bind input to the bytearray: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("LocalProfile", "ConvertandSetImagetoBase64: Could not load selected profile image");
    }
    return base64;
}
```

content://media/external/images/media/3 is what I'm passing into the the method.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Since the scheme of your link is `content` you should probably be using [ContentResolver#openInputStream(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) instead of a `FileInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying the location as a URI, you could try something like:

```
URL url = new URL(imagePath);
Bitmap bmt = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
```